# MAVLink communication unreliable with RFD868x

Tags: python-3.x, communication, serial-communication, mavlink

I'm working on a communication system with [RFD868x](https://store.rfdesign.com.au/rfd-868x-modem/) module, which is supporting mavlink. I'm writing the programs in python with pymavlink. First I test the system with this code:

```
import json
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil
my_dict = {
    "lng": 12.34567898910,
    "lat": 12.34567898910
}
# Establish connection to serial port
master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('/dev/serial0', baud=57600)

while True:
    text = json.dumps(my_dict)
    msg=master.mav.statustext_encode(
        mavutil.mavlink.MAV_SEVERITY_INFO,
        text.encode()
    )
    master.mav.send(msg)
    print("sent")
    time.sleep(1)
```

And on the other side:

```
import json
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil

# Establish connection to serial port
master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('com7', baud=57600)

print("begin")

while True:
    msg = master.recv_match(blocking=True, timeout=.1)
    if msg!=None:
        if msg.get_type() != 'BAD_DATA':
            print (msg)
```

Sometimes I got some BAD_DATA or UNKNOW_DATA, but this informations are delivered. I don't use any other types in this dialect, becouse they were worked horrible (just 1-2 message arrived, and then the tho communication freezed.)

Ofc, I want to communicate not just one direction, so I write a code to send and read datas.

```
import json
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil

master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('/dev/serial0', baud=57600)

def send_message(dats:dict):
    text = json.dumps(dats)
    msg=master.mav.statustext_encode(
        mavutil.mavlink.MAV_SEVERITY_INFO,
        text.encode()
    )
    master.mav.send(msg)
    print("sent")
    time.sleep(.1)

my_dict = {
    "lng": 12.34567898910,
    "lat": 12.34567898910
}
t=time.time()
while True:
    if time.time()-t>1:
        send_message(my_dict)
        t=time.time()
    
    mess = master.recv_match(blocking=True, timeout=1)
    if mess!=None:
        print(mess)
        send_message(my_dict)
```

And tho other side:

```
import json
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil

# Establish connection to serial port
master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('com7', baud=57600)
def cmdLong(dats:list):
    cmd = master.mav.command_long_encode(
    0,
    0,             # target component ID
    mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_USER_1,   # command ID
    0,             # confirmation
    dats[0],             # parameter 1 (not used)
    dats[1],             # parameter 2 (not used)
    dats[2],             # parameter 3 (not used)
    dats[3],             # parameter 4 (not used)
    dats[4], # parameter 5 (string)
    dats[5],              # parameter 6 (not used)
    dats[6]
)
    master.mav.send(cmd)
    print("writed")
    time.sleep(.1)

t=time.time()

print("begin")
while True:
    print("Waiting for message...")
    if time.time()-t>20:
        cmdLong([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
        t=time.time()
        
    msg = master.recv_match(blocking=True, timeout=1)
    if msg!=None:
        if msg.get_type() != 'BAD_DATA':
            print (msg)
```

Now the text messages are arrived until the command message sended. After the command message sended, which isn't detecteed by the reader, the communication was frozen.
After this I test the master-slave type communication with this code, but it doesn't work either.

```
import json
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil

# Establish connection to serial port
master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('/dev/serial0', baud=57600)

def send_message(dats:dict):
    text = json.dumps(dats)
    msg=master.mav.statustext_encode(
        mavutil.mavlink.MAV_SEVERITY_INFO,
        text.encode()
    )
    master.mav.send(msg)
    print("sent")
    time.sleep(.1)

my_dict = {
    "lng": 12.34567898910,
    "lat": 12.34567898910
}
print("begin")
while True:
    mess = master.recv_match(blocking=True, timeout=.1)
    if mess!=None:
        if mess.get_type() != 'BAD_DATA':
            print(mess)
            send_message(my_dict)
```

The other side:

```
import json
import time
from pymavlink import mavutil

# Establish connection to serial port
master = mavutil.mavlink_connection('com7', baud=57600)

def cmdLong(dats:list):
    cmd = master.mav.command_long_encode(
    0,
    0,             # target component ID
    mavutil.mavlink.MAV_CMD_USER_1,   # command ID
    0,             # confirmation
    dats[0],             # parameter 1 (not used)
    dats[1],             # parameter 2 (not used)
    dats[2],             # parameter 3 (not used)
    dats[3],             # parameter 4 (not used)
    dats[4], # parameter 5 (string)
    dats[5],              # parameter 6 (not used)
    dats[6]
)
    master.mav.send(cmd)
    print("writed")
    time.sleep(.1)

print("begin")
cmdLong([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])

while True:
    msg = master.recv_match(blocking=True, timeout=.1)
    if msg!=None:
        if msg.get_type() != 'BAD_DATA':
            print (msg)
            cmdLong([0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
```

Here I've started the programs in the right order, but it doesn't detect anything, (and then of course it doesn't send anything)

I don't know, what is the reason of this errors. If may somebady can help, I will so thankful!

Comment: I think the error was a wrong configuration of `raspi-config`. In the interface settings, the serial interface should be set to enabled and login should be disabled. I'm working on the tests, and if it's wrong, I will delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was not in the codes, it was a wrong setting.

If you want to use RFD868x with raspberry pi's GPIO serial port, you have to **enable** the serial interface, and have to **disable** the serial login shell in `raspi-config`.

After the `sudo raspi-config` command in **Interface Options** and in **Serial Port** the following settings should be used:

[image]

I hope I have helped others.